# can I use OBS as video input to a session?

Tags: opentok

right now, I have a server to issue publisher or subscriber session token

At the frontend, I use React.js with js SDK.

I am able to stream screen share, camera to audiences.

But if I want to integrate something like OBS for more customisable screen. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OBS should be available as a device revealed by [OT.getDevices](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#getDevices) so you can select that is your video device, and then adjust your OBS input as needed.